# User created from command line, can't login successfully

Tags: login

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and i installed it using a user called "jose". From there, i been using it for everything, and i used it for creating, from console, another user, like this:

```
sudo addgroup hadoop
sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser
sudo adduser hduser sudo
```

(i know that i shouldn't add it to sudo).

If i login directly with "hduser", i can pass login successfully but after that, my screen shows me the desktop wallpaper and i can't do much more. There is no toolbar, no icons, and only works the contextual menu, but nothing more.

I suspect that the difference between both users its the way that they have been created, but i searched for information about how `adduser` works by default, and i can't find any helping answer . Any help?

I created this question based on another answer-less, here is the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/918698/open-eclipse-with-a-linux-user-that-doesnt-have-graphical-environment-created) for more details on the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED: to reflect solution.

I don't think that created a $HOME for your user.

You might want to run this too:

```
sudo mkdir /home/hduser #if it doesn't exist
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /home/hduser
```

then try logging in again.

Comment: The folder /home/hduser was already created and almost all the folders have hduser:hadoop, but before executing in a recursive way your second command, i could see that the folder "Desktop" precisely, was with root:root. So, after changing that, i tryed login again and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  It's usually a good idea to test if you can login from the command line before trying the GUI.  It helps narrow down what is broken.  Though glad it's working and fixed for you. :)